# A rake task that executes only if some of its prerequisites have executed

Tags: ruby, rake

In rake, a "normal" task (introduced with the `task` keyword), always executes when invoked. I'd like to know if there is a way to execute the task only if one of its prerequisites were executed.

For instance

```
task :one => "one.txt" do puts "task one" end

file "one.txt" => "two.txt" do cp "two.txt", "one.txt" end
```

I'd like to display "task one" only if "one.txt" wasn't up to date w.r.t. "two.txt" (in other words, only when a file copy happens).

Answer (score 0):

you can make one rake task dependent on another rake task like following, this means task_one and task_two gets executed in the same order when you call task_three

```
task :task_one do
  puts " task_one"

task :task_two do
  puts " task_two"

task :task_three => [ "task_one" "task_two" ] do
  puts "this executes only after task_one and task_two gets executed"
```

Comment: task_three will execute regardless of whether task_one and task_two executed or not (in your example, they always will execute, since they are simple task and not file tasks). My problem is not ordering the task but rather making sure the body of the task runs only if the body of one of the prerequisites has run.